# Run multiple urls to get multiple JSON values

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, ios7

I need to get a single value of JSON data from from four urls each. The code i've written to get JSON data from single url is

```
NSString *url=[NSString   stringWithFormat:@"http://jsondata.in/UserImage.svc/GetUnAnsweredImagesLogCount?UserId=%@",requestString];


        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

        NSURLConnection * connReq = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

        if (connReq) {

            NSLog(@"Connection Sucessful");
            receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
            [self facialimagelogcounturl];

        }
        else
        {

            NSLog(@"failed");

        }
        [connReq start];

        NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSData *respData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
        NSLog(@"Status code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);
        NSLog(@"respdata%@",respData);




    -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:
    (NSURLResponse *)response
    {
        [receivedData setLength:0];

    }

    -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:
    (NSData *)data
    {

        [receivedData appendData:data];


    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

        NSLog(@"ERROR");

    }


    -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    {

        NSError *e;
        NSString *JSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        _userlogcountlabel.text=JSON;
        int json=[JSON intValue];
}
```

I need to display the data in different labels each for a url.For single getting single value from a single url its working fine. I need to make it for multiple urls.

Comment: Loop it for the number of URLs you have. Fetch the JSON response in a loop for each URL.

Comment: here u r showing only one url , where is your four url

Comment: its over karthik i got answer with asynchronus request. i'll post the  in few minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer for my own question.

```
NSString *url1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://jsonddata.in/UserImage.svc/GetNotificationCount?UserId=%@&CategoryId=1",requestString];
    NSURL *URL1 = [NSURL URLWithString:url1];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request1 = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:URL1] ;

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request1 queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        NSArray *results1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
        NSLog(@"facialimage log count  %@",[results1.firstObject objectForKey:@"Notifications"]);

    }];


    NSString *url2=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://jsonddata.in/UserImage.svc/GetNotificationCount?UserId=%@&CategoryId=2",requestString];
    NSURL *URL2 = [NSURL URLWithString:url2];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request2 = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:URL2] ;

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request2 queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        NSArray *results1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
        NSLog(@"clothing log count %@",[results1.firstObject objectForKey:@"Notifications"]);

     }];

    NSString *url3=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://jsondata.in/UserImage.svc/GetNotificationCount?UserId=%@&CategoryId=3",requestString];
    NSURL *URL3 = [NSURL URLWithString:url3];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request3 = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:URL3] ;

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request3 queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        NSArray *results1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
        NSLog(@"object compare log count %@",[results1.firstObject objectForKey:@"Notifications"]);

        }

    }];
```